# Check for big changes in an array of lon , lat pair

Tags: google-bigquery, gis

I am new to sql and looking to see if it is possible to find a discrepancy in an array of lon and lat. How do I check to see if there is a big change of value from the current position to the next
example:
[-79.88523, 30.2566][-65.5523,25.256]
using BigQuery and limited to select only

```
select geo from ( 
SELECT 
routeID ,  json_extract(st_asgeojson(st_makeline( 
array_agg(st_geogpoint(locs.lon, locs.lat) order by 
locs.date))),'$.coordinates') as geo,
FROM 
howardcounty.routebatches
cross join UNNEST(locations) as locs
where  locs.date between {{start_date}} and {{end_date}} 
group by routeID 
order by routeID
limit 1000
)where length(geo)-length(replace(geo,"]","")) > 1+4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `lag` for accessing previous data rows. But first the string has to be parsed into floats:

```
select *,lon-lon_old as diff_lon, lat-lat_old as diff_lat
#RouteID , count(1)
from (
select *, 
    lag(lon) over (partition by RouteID order by row) as lon_old,
    lag(lat) over (partition by RouteID order by row) as lat_old
from (
select 
    row_number() over () as row ,RouteID,
    cast(split(data,",")[offset(0)] as float64) as lon, 
    cast(replace(split(data,",")[offset(1)],"]","") as float64) as lat
from(
select RouteID, split(substring(geo,3),"],[") as data from ( 
SELECT 
routeID ,  json_extract(st_asgeojson(st_makeline( 
array_agg(st_geogpoint(locs.lon, locs.lat) order by 
locs.date))),'$.coordinates') as geo,
FROM 

(select 1 as RouteID,  [struct(5 as lon,5 as lat, current_date() as date), struct(1,2,"2020-01-01") ] as locations UNION ALL 
select 2 as RouteID,  [struct(15 as lon,15 as lat, current_date() as date), struct(1,2,"2020-01-01") ]
)


cross join UNNEST(locations) as locs
#where  locs.date between {{start_date}} and {{end_date}} 
group by routeID 
order by routeID
limit 1000
)where length(geo)-length(replace(geo,"]","")) > 1+4
), unnest(data) data  
)) 
#where lon-lon_old>0.5 or lat-lat_old>0.5
#group by 1
```

An easier example would be

```
With dat as  (select [struct(-79.88523 as A, 30.2566 as B), struct(-65.5523,25.256)] as data )

select *,value.A-old.A as diff_A
from (
select *, lag(value) over (order by row) as old
from (
select row_number() over () as row, value
from dat, unnest (dat.data) as value
)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i cannot use with and am limited to SELECT only on the dataset, how can i rewrite that code for bigquery with select only?

Comment: thanks allot, that did the trick. this however is only showing one set of coordinates from one route, how do i make it so that it does the same for all the other routeID's? i would also need to integrate an if statement to filter out anything that has a bigger change then .5

Comment: a `where` is needed to filter not an `if`. Well comment `*` in the first line and remove the other comments lines. The script works for several routeIDs.